# Toggle class only know the first selected tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $( "button.change" ).click(function() {
    $( "button.change.selected" );
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
  $( "button1.change" ).click(function() {
    $( "button1.change.selected1" );
    $(this).toggleClass("selected1");
  });
});
```

```css
.button{
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image:url(ComputerI.png);//picture1 on
  background-repeat:no-reapeat; 
}

.button1{
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size:13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image:url(calculusO.png);//picture2 on
  background-repeat:no-reapeat; 
}

.selected {
  background:url(ComputerO.png);//picture1 off
}

.selected1 {
  background:url(calculusI.png);//picture2 off
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button change">Click to change image</button><br>
<br>
<button class="button1 change" id="button1 change">Click to change image</button><br>
<br>
```

This is my code, I have two buttons

- Button 1 - toggles Picture 1 on/off
- Button 2 - toggles Picture 2 on/off

The `toggleClass` function is only working on the first button

What do I need to change to get this working?

Comment: Your selector `$("button.change")` is selecting the `<button>` **tag**. Try adding a `"."` in front if you're trying to select the **class**: `$(".button.change")` and `$(".button1.change")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your first selector "$( "button.change" )" will match any button with class "change" - this therefore matches both of your buttons. Therefore when you just click button, it works ok (turns picture1 off) but if you click your second button, it matches your first selector (hence turns picture1 off) and your second selector (turns picture 2 on.

Therefore do:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".button.change").click(function() {
    $("button.change.selected");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected");
  });
  $(".button1.change").click(function() {
    $("button1.change.selected1");
    $(this).toggleClass("selected1");
  });
});
```

```css
.button {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(ComputerI.png); //picture1 on
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.button1 {
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url(calculusO.png); //picture2 on
  background-repeat: no-reapeat;
}

.selected {
  background: url(ComputerO.png); //picture1 off
}

.selected1 {
  background: url(calculusI.png); //picture2 off
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="button change">Click to change image</button><br>
<br>
<button class="button1 change" id="button1 change">Click to change image</button><br>
<br>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That is working. i have think about this for a week....just a point....xD